# Trying to root and install Xposed on Nexus 5 with Lollipop

Tags: rooting, xposed-framework

I'm trying to install Xposed on my Nexus 5 running 5.0.1. I used [Wug's rootkit](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1766475) on Windows to root my device, but first of all it seems that I cannot root. I have gone through the whole process listed on the XDA page. And everything the root kit itself walks me through.

I don't see SuperUser installed after my device reboots; I have done a second test to see if I'm rooted by going into the terminal on my device and checking the symbol after the prompt is a '#' instead of a '$'. It's a '$' currently, which I'm told indicates that I'm not rooted.

It's worth noting I suppose that my device is encrypted, but I don't think this would affect anything since the encryption function encrypts only the /data folder and not the /system folder.

Does someone know if there is an issue with 5.0.1 or perhaps something else I need to be aware of? I'm not sure why this doesn't work.

Comment: Well, first of all `$` does not indicate a non-rooted device; it indicates a non-rooted user, try the `su` command. If it succeeds, then your device is rooted. Also it's still unclear to me what Xposed has to do with your attempt to root your device.

Comment: su doesnt work either

Comment: @GiantTree device must be rooted to install Xposed framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully I don't get burned too badly for this, but I thought I would share this info for people who haven't rooted/unlocked their phones lately (or never have).

In order to root one must unlock first; this functionality is provided in Wug's rootkit as well as the rooting function.

I was trying to mod my phone as little as possible, and I was told by several people that I could root without unlocking first, but it appears that this can never be done (perhaps Wug's rootkit should make that a pop up notification that the user must read in case a scenario presents itself where a user tries doing what I did; this way they can take recourse). In short, I had heard long ago that rooting and/or unlocking could potentially permanently disable Google Wallet, (more deeply speaking, I believe it would disable the use of the NFC chip) and I use NFC for lots of things so I didn't want to risk it if I didn't have to.

I've restored now, and everything has been tested and is fully functional.

Answer (score -1):

Use chainfire's autoroot for root.
This requires adb.
http://autoroot.chainfire.eu